# issue writing to aws lambda /tmp

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Firstly, i am aware that /tmp only had 512mb assigned, this is more than enough for my needs the files i am working with are tiny (~200kb).

I have some code where i pass in a base64 string to a PDF, and then convert it to base64 image file (png) and then embed that inside a new PDF document with new parameters, pages, etc.

When i run this code locally, it works fine : `sls invoke local -f processPendingPdfs`

When i deploy this with `sls deploy`, i get the following error which seems to indicated the file is not being able to read/write to /tmp folder.

```
2022-11-14T16:00:15.137Z    26a28120-adca-48ef-bb9e-6175f1d04ecf    INFO    Working PDF2IMG

2022-11-14T16:00:15.153Z    26a28120-adca-48ef-bb9e-6175f1d04ecf    INFO    Error: spawn pdftocairo ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:472:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn pdftocairo',
  path: 'pdftocairo',
  spawnargs: [ '-png', '/tmp/test.pdf', '/tmp/img' ],
  cmd: 'pdftocairo -png /tmp/test.pdf /tmp/img'
}


2022-11-14T16:00:15.153Z    26a28120-adca-48ef-bb9e-6175f1d04ecf    INFO    imgConvert:  false
2022-11-14T16:00:15.180Z    26a28120-adca-48ef-bb9e-6175f1d04ecf    INFO    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/img-1.png'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at Function.open (/var/task/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4628:19)
    at PDFDocument.openImage (/var/task/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4771:24)
    at PDFDocument.image (/var/task/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4672:22)
    at /var/task/utils/pdfFiles/FileMaker.js:40:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/tmp/img-1.png'
}
```

What is the cause of this?

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const { Base64Encode } = require("base64-stream");
const fs = require("fs");
let _ = require("lodash");
//let chart = require("../charts/createChartPhase2");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let axios = require("axios");

require("dotenv").config();

var pdftoimage = require("pdftoimage");

module.exports.Pdf2Img = async (data) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    try {
      //do stuff
      console.log("Data to write to file:", data);
      fs.writeFileSync("test.pdf", data, { encoding: "base64" });
      var file = "test.pdf";
      console.log("Working PDF2IMG");

      // Returns a Promise
      await pdftoimage(file, {
        format: "png", // png, jpeg, tiff or svg, defaults to png
        prefix: "img", // prefix for each image except svg, defaults to input filename
        outdir: "/tmp", // path to output directory, defaults to current directory
      })
        .then(function () {
          console.log("Conversion done");
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          resolve(false);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
};
```